# back&: How to send signup page with different role to two kinds of users

Tags: javascript, authentication, backend

I use [back&](http://www.backand.com) platform and I have two kind of users:

users that are considered as `providers` and others that considered `consumer`.

In `Security & Auth/Configuration` section there is `Public App` with `Invited users default assigned role:` so I can attach role to one kind of users

But how can I send the invitation page with `provider` role? And other user that come to the site and signup get `consumer` or `user` role?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "SECURITY ACTIONS" add a new action in Before Create which update the Role based on parameters you sent in the signup.
In the action the code is:

```
userInput.Role = 'ReadOnly';
```

In order to send additional information to the signup use the parameters in Backand.signup(...), see more docs here: http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/security/#saving-additional-parameters-during-sign-up

Comment: ok, so if I undrstand in that method all users register to same table `users` but with diffrent role that I can change in `security action event`.

but what if I want to save them in diffrent table because they have entrly diffrent schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hidden field tag and pass the role as the value in the invitations form. So when visitors sign up via the invitations page the role is predefined.